# Sending automatic mail if column get updated

Tags: google-apps-script

In spread sheet , by using app scrip i would like  to send email if value in column get updated

I tried edit trigger but not worked please provide app script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send Email on User Edit of a column.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();//you fill in all of the question marks
  if(sh.getName() == "?" && e.range.columnStart == ?) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.range.offset(0,?).getDisplayValue(),e.range.offset(0,?).getDisplayValue(),e.range.offset(0,?).getDisplayValue());
  }
}
```

Can't run function from script editor or menu unless you provide an intermediate function to supply the event object e.

Comment: thanx for solution it is use full and working